# How to make onchange event in javascript work from a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my Asp.net MVC project a view index that contains a block in which opens the PartialViews Edit Details and Delete in a Modal window. Everything works correctly, but I'm having a problem with the Event of my "PersonNature" Combobox that is not working on the Change event.

The combobox PersonNature is in the PartialView _Person and is rendered inside the PartialView Create. When I select a PersonNature, in the combobox, in thesis, one must give a POST for the Action to change some data and return again to the PartialView Create in Modal form, but this is not happening. The event change is not responding ... 
What is wrong with my event?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $('a[data-modal]').on('click', function (e) {       
        openmodal(this.href);
        return false;
    });
    $('#modalPessoa').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#contentModal').html('');
    }); 
 $('#PessoaNatureza').change(function () {
            openmodal(this.href);
            return false;
    }); 
           
});
function openmodal(url) {
    $('#contentModal').load(url, function () {
        $('#modalPessoa').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show'); 
        //$("#PessoaNatureza").change(function () {
        //   document.getElementById('frmCreate').submit();
        //});        

        bindForm(this);
    });
}
function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        window.location = window.location;
                        window.location.reload();

                    } else {
                        $('#contentModal').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

```js
@using SistemaComercial.Domain.ValueObjects
@model SistemaComercial.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cadastrar Nova Pessoa";
}

<div>
    <form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Pessoa" id="frmCreate">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="modal-shadow">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center"> @ViewData["Title"] </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div id="validationSummary" class="text-center">
                    <vc:summary />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="exampleTabsOne" role="tabpanel">
                                <div class="form-horizontal">

                                    <div class="form-group row">
          <label  asp-for="PessoaNatureza" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
          <div class="col-md-3">
           <select asp-for="PessoaNatureza" asp-items="Model.PessoasNaturezas" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow"></select>
           <span asp-validation-for="PessoaNatureza" class="text-danger"></span>
          </div>            
         </div>

                                    @if (Model.PessoaNatureza == PessoaNatureza.Fisica)
                                    {
                                        @*<div id="divPessoaJuridica">
                                                @await Html.PartialAsync("_PessoaJuridica")
                                            </div>*@
                                        <div id="divPessoaFisica">
                                            @await Html.PartialAsync("_PessoaFisica")
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                    else if (Model.PessoaNatureza == PessoaNatureza.Juridica)
                                    {
                                        @*<div id="divPessoaFisica" style="display:none">
                                                @await Html.PartialAsync("_PessoaFisica")
                                            </div>*@
                                        <div id="divPessoaJuridica">
                                            @await Html.PartialAsync("_PessoaJuridica")
                                        </div>
                                    }

                                </div>
                           
                    </div>

                    @*<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon wb-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Gravar</button>
                                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    <span title="Retornar à Lista" class="icon wb-arrow-left"></span> Retornar à lista
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>*@

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="btnSalvar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon wb-check"></i> Salvar </button>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span title="Fechar" class="icon wb-close"></span> Fechar
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My Modal Block (Index)

```js
<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="modalPessoa" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 65%; height: auto;">
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div id="contentModal"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My PartialView _Pessoa:

```js
@model SistemaComercial.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Pessoa";
}

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" disabled />
            <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        @*<a class="btn btn-primary" id="examplePopWithTable" href="javascript:void(0)" data-title="Códigos de Pessoa">Códigos</a>
        <div class="hidden" id="examplePopoverTable" >
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PessoaEntidadeViewModel.Id)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PessoaEntidadeViewModel.PessoaTipo)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PessoaEntidadeViewModel.PessoaFilial)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.PessoasEntidades)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pessoa.Id)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PessoaTipo)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PessoaFilialId)
                            </td>


                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>*@

    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label  asp-for="PessoaNatureza" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select id="PessoaNatureza" asp-for="PessoaNatureza" asp-items="Model.PessoasNaturezas" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="PessoaNatureza" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        @*<label asp-for="PessoaEntidadeViewModel.PessoaFilialId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select asp-for="PessoaEntidadeViewModel.PessoaFilialId" asp-items="Model.PessoaEntidadeViewModel.Filiais" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="show-tick show-menu-arrow"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="PessoaEntidadeViewModel.PessoaFilialId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Although you haven't given enough code to be certain, I would guess that, since you define your events before you create your modal, that the event handler attaches itself to nothing, since that combobox element won't exist until your modal is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you didnt give enough code to work with, I think your dropdown element is losing its binding

Try changing this

```
$('#PessoaNatureza').change(function () {
        openmodal(this.href);
        return false;
    });
```

To this

```
$('.modal-primary').on('change', '#PessoaNatureza', function() {
  openmodal(this.href);
            return false;
});
```

that should retain the binding when the modal opens up with your create html inside it. `$('.modal-primary')` works as the base of your change event which I found on the image in your modal

Comment: Further info on how and why this works can be found at http://api.jquery.com/on/ in the section entitled "Direct and delegated events"

Comment: Thank you guys! The solution used was the friend of @EmpJemz: $ ('modal-primary'). On ('change', '#PessoaNatureza', function (e) {$ ('# frmCreate'). ;